# How to create a date picker in an android app

Tags: android

I want to show a date picker on a button click. 
Is there a control for that to be used or do I need to create my own in the onClick() method of the button. If so any suggestion as to what to do there?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you mean to say date picker ?

Comment: User `DatePickerDialog`

Comment: There is an inbuilt date and time picker dialog in android and many more libraries available one of them would be https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker
Use anyone of your choice..

Comment: *There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.*

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following code.

CalenderActivity.java

```
public class CalenderActivity extends Activity implements OnDateChangedListener, OnMonthChangedListener {

private static final DateFormat FORMATTER = SimpleDateFormat.getDateInstance();
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");


@Bind(R.id.calendarView)
MaterialCalendarView widget;
@Bind(R.id.textView)
TextView textView;
Button ok;
int new_date,new_month;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calender);

    getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    widget.setOnDateChangedListener(this);
    widget.setOnMonthChangedListener(this);




    widget.setSelectedDate(Calendar.getInstance());

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    System.out.println("Current time => " + c.getTime());

    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
    textView.setText(formattedDate);


   // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"date is :"+new_date+"/"+new_month+"/"+c.get(Calendar.YEAR),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



    ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ok_button);
    ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
            returnIntent.putExtra("result", textView.getText().toString());
            setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
            CalenderActivity.this.finish();


        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onDateChanged(@NonNull MaterialCalendarView widget, @Nullable CalendarDay date) {
    if(date == null) {
        textView.setText(null);
    }
    else {

       // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "selected date is :  " + date.getDate(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        textView.setText(fmt.format(date.getDate()));
    }
}

@Override
public void onMonthChanged(MaterialCalendarView widget, CalendarDay date) {

 //   Toast.makeText(this, FORMATTER.format(date.getDate()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

activity_calender.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
          android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
          android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
          android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
          tools:context=".BasicActivity"
>

<com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView
    android:id="@+id/calendarView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text=""
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/ok_button"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="OK"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_calender_bg"
    android:positiveButtonText="Ok"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
```

At last pass Intent in "On click" of the button.
  Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

try following library for open calender in dialog.

https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker

and display dialog on button's click event like following.

```
Button ivLaunchPicker=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
ivLaunchPicker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // DialogFragment to host SublimePicker
                SublimePickerFragment pickerFrag = new SublimePickerFragment();
                pickerFrag.setCallback(mFragmentCallback);

                // Options
                Pair<Boolean, SublimeOptions> optionsPair = getOptions();

                if (!optionsPair.first) { // If options are not valid
                    Toast.makeText(Sampler.this, "No pickers activated",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                // Valid options
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putParcelable("SUBLIME_OPTIONS", optionsPair.second);
                pickerFrag.setArguments(bundle);

                pickerFrag.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, 0);
                pickerFrag.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "SUBLIME_PICKER");
            }
        });
```